# How to delet "undeleteable files"

Tags: lubuntu, delete, trash

Running Lubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Bleachbit (as root) will not delete three files located in:

```
/root/.local/share/Trash/files
```

The files in question are:

```
/root/.local/share/Trash/files/**menu-cached-:0**
/root/.local/share/Trash/files/**pcmanfm-socket--0**
/root/.local/share/Trash/files/**at-spi2-socket-5044**
```

They are all 0 byte files.

I can't delete them manually as root either, they keep coming back.

Thoughts on this would be great

Comment: Check `lsattr` if there is * immutable* attribute . Also if you say they coming back , you mean they where delete and getting back again ?

Comment: those are sockets, so them being 0 size is correct

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are seeing an error message when you try to delete them as root (I assume you are doing a sudo rm -f), the issue doesn't seem to be that they cannot be deleted.  The issue appears to be that some process is recreating them.

You could try dropping down to single user mode (if available) to see if they are being recreated then.